# Adding strong tag in a variable

Tags: javascript

I have 2 variables:

```
const type = "Hell";
const name = "Hello World!";
```

I would like to add a `<strong>` tag after whatever the value of `type` is.

So it should look like this: Hell**o World!**

How can I do this?

Comment: Are there only one instance of `type` in `name` or could there be more?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir there is only one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first take the remaining part of the string. Then [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) that string part to form new string as part of the main string:

```js
const type = "Hell";
let name = "Hello World!";
let remaining = name.replace(type,'');
name = name.replace(remaining, '<strong>' +remaining+ '</strong>');
document.write(name);
```

For case insensitivity you have to use `new RegExp()` with insensitivity flag (`i`):

```js
const type = "hell";
let name = "Hello World!";
var regEx = new RegExp(type, "i"); // pass the flag here
let remaining = name.replace(regEx, '');
name = name.replace(remaining, '<strong>' +remaining+ '</strong>');
document.write(name);
```

Comment: Good answer, however you would need to ensure that `type` is at the start of `name`

Comment: Thank you, this works great. For now it only works if `Hell` starts with a upper case. Is it possible to make it work without attention to upper and lower case?

Comment: @RezaSaadati, I have updated the answer with another solution for case insensitivity. Please check thanks...

Answer (score 2):

So I think you are looking for something like this:

```
const type = "Hell";
const name = "Hello, World!";
var rex = new RegExp(type);
name.replace(rex, type+"<strong>")+"</strong>";
```

Which will result in this -> `"Hell<strong>o, World!</strong>"`

Which will appear like this -> "Hell**o, World!**"

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by using a regex `(type)(.+)` to replace the first captured group `(type)` by itself (`$1`) and the second captured group `(.+)` by itself wrapped in the `<strong>` tag (`<strong>$2</strong>`):

```js
const type = "Hell";
const name = "Hello World!";

const regex = new RegExp("(" + type + ")(.+)", "i");

const result = name.replace(regex, "$1<strong>$2</strong>");

console.log(result);
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

The `"i"` passed to `RegExp` is the ignore case modifier.

**Note:** If you want to include empty strings as well (for example `type = "Hell"` and `name = "Hell"` and the result is `"Hell<strong></strong>"` instead of `"Hell"`), then replace `.+` with `.*`.